# How to replicate this in Android studio from Intellij?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Intellij has the option 'import module from existing resources'.

Android studio seemingly only has 'New module' or 'import module'.

[Here is the result of both of these.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97tjuxi8iimhhkc/q.png?dl=0)

I much more prefer the Intellij way as it is *way* more organized, since it allows you to basically have multiple projects open at once. The Android Studio way does let you have them both open, but they are not treated as separate projects and or libraries, but instead as a different folder.

Is there any way to do this, or at least replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project space and select New->Module and import from existing source. Find the path of your other project. When importing, you may rename the app files to "app2" or something. See if that's what you want.

[image]

Remember that Android Studio is built off of IntelliJ Idea, so a lot of the settings are similar. Personally, depending on my projects, I like to have several windows open for different projects since it gets crowded but I can understand why you'd want them in the same project space.

Comment: While I do appreciate the answer, I believe that is an old version of Android Studio. Unfortunately, I have no option to do so anymore, on the newest version.

Comment: @AndrewNo Maybe I can still help you out. I'm using 1.2.1.1, check what version you have. I'll update now actually.

Comment: I am using 2.1 Preview 3